# Call Python object's variable as a function without passing the calling object

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-methods

I have a structure something like this:

```
def foobar():
    print('FOOBAR!')

class SampleClass:
    foo = foobar
    def printfunc(self):
        self.foo()
```

This doesn't work because the original foobar function can't handle `self` being passed to it -- it wasn't part of any class or object to begin with. Python won't let me add the `@staticmethod` decorator either.

I have no control over the definition of `foobar`, and I may have to override the value of `foo` in subclasses.

How can I call foo, without passing the object calling it?

Comment: Why not just `def foo(self): foobar()`?

Comment: @Huey Because in this specific case, it's *not* something I can define. It's an external method, and will be overridden with another external method in a subclass.

Comment: Try to use `classmethod`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Decorators are plain functions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator), you should be able to call `staticmethod(foobar)` explicitly in the class definition

```
class SampleClass:
    foo = staticmethod(foobar)
    def printfunc(self):
        self.foo() # Prints 'FOOBAR!'
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach from user2357112's comment seems to work, too:

```
def foobar():
        print('FOOBAR!')

def foobaz():
        print('FooBAZ!')

class SampleClass:
        def foo(self):
                foobar()

        def printfunc(self):
                self.foo()

class DerivedClass(SampleClass):
        def foo(self):
                foobaz()

sample = SampleClass()
sample.printfunc() # FOOBAR!

derived = DerivedClass()
derived.printfunc() # FooBAZ!
```

If return values shall make it through, you need `return` statements on all levels, though:

```
def foobar():
        print('FOOBAR!')
        return 'foo'

def foobaz():
        print('FooBAZ!')
        return 'baz'

class SampleClass:
        def foo(self):
                return foobar()

        def printfunc(self):
                return self.foo()

class DerivedClass(SampleClass):
        def foo(self):
                return foobaz()

sample = SampleClass()
s = sample.printfunc() # FOOBAR!
print(s) # foo

derived = DerivedClass()
d = derived.printfunc() # FooBAZ!
print(d) # baz
```

Comment: It's not simply enough to run the function with a second function, I think. I had to greatly prune the example I gave to its simplest components, but there are some `yield` statements floating around in there too -- not sure how this would effect them.

Comment: Well, while it's appreciated (and expected) that you boil examples down to their relevant parts, make sure that everything that *is* relevant (to you/to your problem or question) is still included. [Einstein's razor](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) is as important as Occam's.

Comment: @Z̷͙̗̻͖̣̹͉̫̬̪̖̤͆ͤ̓ͫͭ̀̐͜͞ͅͅαлγo: It should work just fine. `foobar` is a generator function, and `foo` won't be, but `foo` should return the generator iterator returned by `foobar` as if `foo` were a generator function itself.